# String to unicode code point escpe sequences in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Here is my problem... I have a "normal" String like :

```
Hello World
```

And unlike all the other subjects I have found, I WANT to print it as it's Unicode Codepoint Escape value !

The output I am looking for is something like this:

```
\u0015\u0123
```

If anyone has an idea :)

Comment: `u\0015\0123` is not a UTF8 string.

Comment: Moreover, UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, so printing ASCII characters encoded to UTF-8 is still ASCII **too**.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `\u0015\u0123` are Unicode codepoint escapes, they are **not** UTF-8 either.

Comment: i don't understand what output you want.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, will edit to correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding ASCII codepoints *only*. UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, any ASCII codepoints are encoded to the *same bytes* as ASCII would use. What you are printing is correct, that **is** UTF-8.

Use some non-ASCII codepoints to see the difference:

```
>>> 'Hello world with an em-dash: \u2014\n'.encode('utf8')
b'Hello world with an em-dash: \xe2\x80\x94\n'
```

Python will just use the characters themselves when it shows you a `bytes` value with printable ASCII bytes in it. Any byte value that is *not* printable is shown as a `\x..` escape code, or a single-character escape sequence if there is one (`\n` for newline).

From your example output, on the other hand, you seem to be expecting to output Python unicode literal escape codes:

```
>>> '\u0015\u0123'
'\x15ģ'
```

Since U+0123 is printable, Python 3 just shows it; the non-printable U+0015 (`NEGATIVE ACKNOWLEDGE`) is a codepoint in the `0x00`-`0xFF` range and is shown using the shorter `\x..` escape notation.

To show *only* unicode escape sequences for your text, you need to process it character by character:

```
>>> input_text = 'Hello World!'
>>> print(''.join('\\u{:04x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in input_text))
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0021
>>> input_text = 'Hello world with an em-dash: \u2014\n'
>>> print(''.join('\\u{:04x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in input_text))
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0020\u0077\u0069\u0074\u0068\u0020\u0061\u006e\u0020\u0065\u006d\u002d\u0064\u0061\u0073\u0068\u003a\u0020\u2014\u000a
```

It is important to stress that this is **not** UTF-8, however.

Comment: I'm aware that is what is currently happening but that isn't the output I'm looking for.
I want the output to be the numeric value as in \u2014

Comment: @user2243892: Then you need to be *far clearer* in what you are looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ord* to the encoded bytes into numbers and use string formatting you display their hex values.

```
>>> s = u'Hello World \u0664\u0662'
>>> print s
Hello World ٤٢
>>> print ''.join('\\x%02X' % ord(c) for c in s.encode('utf-8'))
\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C\x64\x20\xD9\xA4\xD9\xA2
```